# Different outputs of DCT from OpenCV and Scipy.fftpack.dctn?

Tags: python, opencv, scipy, dct

I am calculating DCT of grayscale image of size 32x32

- Using OpenCV

```
def _dct(image):
    result = cv2.dct(np.float32(image)/255.0)
    return (result * 255.0)
```

- Using Scipy.fftpack.dctn

```
dctn(image)
```

Output of both functions first using **cv2.dct()** then using **scipy.fftpack.dctn()**
[image: Output]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason is of this behaviour is listed here
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.fftpack.dct.html

Answer : **dctn(image, norm = "ortho")**

Reason : In case of norm = "ortho" resulting DCT is multiplied with scaling factor f which results in same output as given by _dct using OpenCV.

```
f = sqrt(1/4N) when k = 0 
    sqrt(1/2N) otherwise
```